# how to add NaN values to row names of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a data.frame but I want some rows to have the name NaN and I have not yet achieved such an effect

```r
tb = as.array(c(1:32))
dim(tb) <- c(8, 4)# (rows, cols)
lb1 = c("Hi","R","Lang","stat") # cols names 4

lb2 = rep(NaN,length(lb1)*2 )
#lb2[c(2*(1:length(lb1))- 1) ] = c(lb1)
lb2[seq(from = 1, length.out = length(lb1), by = 2)] = lb1 
rownames(tb) <- lb2
colnames(tb) <- lb1
frm = as.data.frame(tb,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,check.names=T,fix.empty.names=F)
```

for example when use `rownames(frm)`:

```r
[1] "Hi"     "NaN."   "R"      "NaN..1" "Lang"   "NaN..2" "stat"   "NaN..3"
```

I want "NaN." , "NaN..1" and the others. **I just need NaN out without attributes**

Comment: What do you mean by `I just need NaN out without attributes`. What is your expected output? Do you want all "NaN...." rownames to turn into only "NaN" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have duplicated values in `rownames`.

```
rownames(frm)
> [1] "Hi"    "NaN"   "R"     "NA..1" "Lang"  "NA..2" "stat"  "NA..3"
rownames(frm)[4] <- NaN
```

you get

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Similarly, missing values `NA` are not allowed.

If you do

```
rownames(frm)[2] <- NA
```

you get:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  missing values in 'row.names' are not allowed
```

The fact you see "NaN", "NaN..1" and so on is R trying to make it works anyway by converting them to characters and deduplicating them.

Comment: then it is not possible, well I wanted to use in knitr and with the NaN draw an unnamed cell

Comment: Can't you add a 'name' column for that purpose?